# Django-REST-Framework validate fails: "this field is required"

Tags: django, file-upload, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

some context here... I have a Room object that has a list of pictures. Right now I'm stuck at the POST method (create a new room with pictures). But I keep getting the validation error "this field is required".

**model**

```html
class Room(models.Model):
    CONDO = 'condo'
    HOUSE = 'house'
    OTHER = 'other'
    ROOM_TYPES = [(CONDO, 'condo'), (HOUSE, 'house'), (OTHER, 'other')]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=ROOM_TYPES)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    info = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='listings', null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    include_utility = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    allow_pet = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    include_parking = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    include_furniture = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class RoomPicture(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images', null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['room', 'image']
```

**serializer**

```html
class RoomPictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
        model = RoomPicture
        fields =['id','image']
        
class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  # images = serializers.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
  images = RoomPictureSerializer(many=True)
  class Meta:
    model = Room
    fields = ['id', 'owner', 'name', 'price', 'type', 'location', 'info', 
              'start_date', 'end_date', 'is_available' , 'include_utility' ,'allow_pet',
              'include_parking', 'include_furniture', 'images']
    
  def create(self, validated_data):
    images_data = validated_data.pop('images')
    room = Room.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for image_data in images_data:
      RoomPicture.objects.create(room=room, image=image_data["image"])
    return room
```

**views**

```html
def convert(image):
    dict = {}
    # dict['id'] = 0
    dict['image'] = image
    return dict

class RoomViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # permission_classes = [
    #     permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    # ]
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    serializer_class = RoomSerializer
    queryset = Room.objects.all()
    
    def create(self, request):
        
        # converts querydict to original dict
        dict_data = dict((request.data).lists())
        dict_data['images'] = list(map(convert, dict_data['images']))
        print(request.data)
        query_dict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
        query_dict.update(MultiValueDict(dict_data))
        print(query_dict)
        serializer = RoomSerializer(data=query_dict)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(owner=request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data) 
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

What I don't understand is that in my view, I explicitly passed in query_dict which has an 'images' key. But for some reason the validator does not recognize it.

so the request.data looks like this

```html
<QueryDict: { 'name': [ 'The Building'], 'price': [ '900'], 'type': [ 'condo'], 'location': [ '100 Trump Rd'], 'info': [ '1 bedroom + 1 bath / share kitchen & living room'], 'start_date': [ '2021-09-01'], 'end_date': [ '2021-12-31'], 'is_available': [
  'true'], 'include_utility': [ 'true'], 'include_parking': [ 'true'], 'include_furniture': [ 'true'], 'allow_pet': [ 'true'], 'images': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: Phillip-Square-Blair-House-Conference-Room.jpg (image/jpeg)>,
  <InMemoryUploadedFile: Phillip-Square-Blair-House-Gym.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

and the tuned query_dict looks like this

```html
<QueryDict: {'name': ['The Building'], 'price': ['900'], 'type': ['condo'], 'location': ['100 Trump Rd'], 'info': ['1 bedroom + 1 bath / share kitchen & living room'], 'start_date': ['2021-09-01'], 'end_date': ['2021-12-31'], 'is_available': ['true'], 'include_utility': ['true'], 'include_parking': ['true'], 'include_furniture': ['true'], 'allow_pet': ['true'], 'images': [{'image': <InMemoryUploadedFile: Phillip-Square-Blair-House-Conference-Room.jpg (image/jpeg)>}, {'image': <InMemoryUploadedFile: Phillip-Square-Blair-House-Gym.jpg (image/jpeg)>}]}>
```

whether I pass in serializer = RoomSerializer(data=request.data) or serializer = RoomSerializer(data=query_dict) I always get the same error...

Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The default ModelSerializer implementation does not allow nested serializer data so `serializer.is_valid()` will return false hence the error.
Even using the [drf_writable_nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested) module doesn't work for it as well.

Based on what you're trying to do, there are 3 options that I can advise:

1. Write your serializer explicitly with `serializers.Serializer` though, that will be a lot of code but, it'll satisfy the nesting.
2. Create separate views and serializers for the RoomPicture model. This way, on your client-side, you'll initially create the Room object then upload the images afterwards.
3. If you have a specific amount of images for the Room object, you can add image fields to the Room model e.g

```
class Room(models.Model):
    ...
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    ...

    @property
    def images(self):
        images_list = []
        image_fields = [self.image1, self.image2, self.image3]
        for image_count, image_field in enumerate(image_fields, start=1):
            if image_field:
                image_dict = {'path': image_field.url, 'count': image_count}
                images_list.append(image_dict)
        return images_list
```

If the images can be more than 5, you might want to use option 2.

You'll have to add `images` to your RoomSerializer as a `ReadOnlyField()`, it'll serialize the data as a list of objects just like what you'll get from using FK.

You'll be able to create and update your Room data with the images altogether.
To delete a particular image, just set the field as null. That's why I added `count` to the `image_dict` data to help know which image to update from the client-side.

You should also install [django-cleanup](https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup) to help delete the previous image after an update has been made to any of the image fields.